# RichIPythonWidget import side effect on pkgutil module

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

Apparently, importing RichIPythonWidget has an impact on module pkgutil.

## Test environment:

IPython version: 2.1.0
python versions: 2.7 & 2.7.6

## Code showing issue:

```
import os
import pkgutil

print 'Before 1 ... '
pkgutil.find_loader('os') # call 1
print 'After call 1 ... '

from IPython.qt.console.rich_ipython_widget import RichIPythonWidget

print 'Before call 2 ... '
pkgutil.find_loader('os') # call 2
print 'After call 2 ... '
```

## Output:

```
Before call 1 ... 
After call 1 ... 
Before call 2 ... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "issue.py", line 11, in <module>
    pkgutil.find_loader('os') # call 2
  File "/u/bl/Dev/work/inkqt/opt.SuSE-11.4/lib64/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 467, in find_loader
    loader = importer.find_module(fullname)
TypeError: find_module() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

As far as i understand, my issue seems to be related to objects added to **sys.meta_path**
by **IPython** but used with the wrong interface by **pkgutil** module.
But it's hard for me to decide who's guilty...

Any workaround would be greatly appreciated.

thx

-benoit

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the Qt ImportDenier installed by IPython in IPython/external/qt_loaders.py.  The find_module method does not respect the PEP302 signature of `finder.find_module(fullname, path=None)`, where the path is optional.

I submitted an issue on IPython: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5932.